# how to convert str to float in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, typeconverter

I am using below line to read a csv file where column B ends as str format and I do not manage to convert it to float directly:

```
   df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=";", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

this produces a dataframe where all columns are in str format:

```
          A       B
    0   Emma     -20,50
    1   Filo     -15,75
    2   Theo      17,23
```

As you may notice the decimals are separated by ',' instead of '.' because it's German csv. 
I tried the following already (to no avail):

```
  ..., dtype={'B': np.float32}, decimal= ',' , ....
```

Any idea how I could get it done in the reading process?

Amending after reading the csv is working (but this is an inefficient additional step I would like to avoid), this is what I use:

```
 df['B'] = df['B'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it works nice, I only omit `dtype={'B': np.float32}`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""A;B
0;Emma;-20,50
1;Filo;-15,75
2;Theo;17,23"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", decimal= ',')
print (df)
      A      B
0  Emma -20.50
1  Filo -15.75
2  Theo  17.23

print (df.dtypes)
A     object
B    float64
dtype: object
```

EDIT:

I think problem can be some decimals are `.` and some `,`, then use `converters`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""A;B
0;Emma;-20,50
1;Filo;-15.75
2;Theo;17,23"""


def converter(x):
    return float(x.replace(',','.'))

#define each column
converters={'B': converter}

#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 sep=";", 
                 encoding = "ISO-8859-1", 
                 converters=converters)
print (df)

0  Emma -20.50
1  Filo -15.75
2  Theo  17.23

print (df.dtypes)
A     object
B    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer but for me that still does not work. I find this very strange.

Comment: no, this is not the problem. all decimals really are ','. But there are some 0 values (so no decimal) and some NaN.

Comment: If data are not confidental, is possible share `csv` - by dropbox, ggogle docs...?

Comment: sorry, cannot share this.

Comment: indeed in the csv there are some '.' (like format 1.230,45)  but they are located in other columns. Could it be that they still prevent from converting remaining rows from converting to float?

Comment: I think no. But I have one idea - filter csv by parameter nrows first with 100, then maybe 150.. and find what value causes problem.

Comment: There is problem I cannot simulate your data - I try add NaN, 0 and it still nice works. And it is interesting that `df['B'].str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)` works and solution with converters no. So good luck and if my solution dont help you (it seems) I can delete it.

Comment: thank you jezrael, will try around a bit further. fortunately my workaround is working anyways so I can at least procede.